# I also have a camera tripod that I am intrigued with. I can not find anything on line about it or the brand. I need some help plz. I have some picture

Tags: tripod

Can anyone help me identify this tripod. I believe it was used for photography of still images and people at a photography shop. Also does it hold any value?

Comment: I was unable to post a pic. How do I go about that

Comment: @RobbKidd [Edit your question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/132741/edit), and in the edit box, click on the "Image" icon to upload an image to your post.

Comment: @scottbb Can users with a reputation of "1" embed photos?

Comment: @RobbKidd If you still can't post a pic, please upload it to a hosting site such as [imgur](https://imgur.com/) and post the direct link to the photo in a comment here. One of us will edit it into your question.

Comment: @MichaelC I believe so; the [new user restrictions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) allow 8 links.

Comment: Is allowing links the same thing as allowing embedded photos?